# Why are changesets missing from my Track Changeset view

Tags: change-tracking

I'm really hoping that someone is going to be able to help us out here...

Imagine the following branch hierarchy:

```
Main +--> Dev +--> Project 1
     |        |
     |        +--> Project 2
     |
     +--> Release 1
```

Now imagine that I have changesets 1 & 2 in Project 1, and changesets 3, 4 & 5 in Project 2.

Both these projects are included in Release 1, so we merge changesets 1 & 2 into Dev as changeset 6, then on into Main as changeset 7. We then merge changesets 3, 4 & 5 into Dev as changeset 8, then on into Main as changeset 9. We then merge changesets 8 & 9 into Release 1 as changeset 10.

When we then view the history of Release 1, we correctly see only changeset 10. Everything is OK this far, and we can verify that all the changes from both Project branches have been successfully merged into Release 1.

We now right-click and track changeset 10, and switch the mode to timeline, ensuring that all relevant branches were selected in the branch selection window (i.e. Release 1, Project 1 and Project 2 branches - the intermediate branches are automatically included).

The problem we are having is that intermittently, source changesets from the Project branches are meing missed off the tracking. THe example above represents this morning's merge, and the tracking shows all changesets except the changesets 1 & 2 from the Project 1 branch. It shows changeset 6, where changesets 1 & 2 were merged into Dev, but does not show the changesets that were included.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this may be happening? And how to fix it?

Cheers.

Comment: You are saying that the same user, sees various tracking outputs for a given changeset? In that case, I would simply file a bug report in MS

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  For me, it appears to occur when changesets are merged out of sequence (cherry picked).